# Azure Pipeline storage file trigger doesn't fire

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

[image]I´ve created an **Azure Synapse Analytics Pipeline** that must be triggered by the creation of a file within a **Azure Gen2 storage account**.

Somehow the **blob creation event** (i.e. when I upload the file in the corresponding container and folder) doesn´t fire anything and the pipeline does not start. I´ve registered the *Microsoft.EventGrid* and *Microsoft.Synapse* resource providers in the subscription, [as suggested by the Microsoft official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-event-trigger?tabs=data-factory).

Am I missing anything? As far as I know, and according to the Microsoft documentation and the many tutorials I've read, I don´t need any Event Topic/Event subscription...

Comment: Can you share your Trigger configuration? I do this often in Logic Apps, and the syntax for properly referring to the container/folder/file patterns can be finicky.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the content type of the file :
[image]

usually when that is blank, event trigger is not initiated

Comment: Hi @Nandan, thank you very much for your reply and for your hint. The content type is in my case "application/json", so I guess it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your scenario in my environment, and it works for me (i.e., when I upload the file in the corresponding container and folder). Let me share my implementation and then you can compare with yours.

[image]

This is the setup for the trigger

[image]

**The trigger is firing as expected.**

- **Files uploaded date time**
  [image]
- **Trigger firing date time**
  [image]

Comment: Hi @PratikLad, thank you very much for your help! I have the exact some configuration as yours - and the trigger still doesn´t fire. Did you have to configure Azure EventGrid before you created the trigger in Synapse?

Comment: No, I have not configured Azure EventGrid before creating trigger in synapse. Are you getting any error? if so, please share that.

Comment: Hi @PratikLad, I've got no error... the trigger simply doesn't fire.

Answer (score 0):

I still didn´t figure out what is not working, so I implemented a workaround: a simple ADF pipeline looping for files in the landing zone. The pipeline is associated with a normal schedule trigger (it runs 3 times a day) and it calls in turn the pipeline I originally wanted to be triggered by the file creation trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update: I´ve contacted the Azure Support and together with a representative we've been investigating the issue. It seems to be a very common problem, it occurs very often in several Azure implementations.

It seems the storage account where the event should be triggered has no **event grid subscription** associated to it. It should be however automatically created when the trigger is created and activated within Azure Synapse Workspace.

[image: Missing Even Grid Subscription within the Storage Account]

Comment: I seem to have similar issue. When I try to publish storage trigger from Azure Synapse Analytics, I often get a vague error: "Failed to subscribe to events for event trigger {my_event_trigger_name}". When I go look at Event Subscriptions for my storage accounts, there is nothing there.

Comment: Strangely, I just created a similar pipeline in Azure Data Factory (ADF) and it registered the event grid subscription automatically when I published the trigger. Who knows why Azure Synapse Analytics (ASA) was failing to correctly perform the registration. Regardless of cause, my file trigger is working fine in ADF even though it doesn't work in ASA. *NOTE: You may still have to register Microsoft.EventGrid with your subscription, but ADF will **at least** setup the storage account when you publish the trigger. That's more than I can say for ASA at this time.*

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the Microsoft support I eventually found out the problem.

It was all about Azure Synapse Analytics lacking the proper permissions. Granting the "owner" permission to Synapse within the storage account solved the issue - without a proper "admin" role, Synapse cannot create the underlying objects in Events Grid.